# Toggling listview web part content source

Tags: web-part, jquery, list-view-web-part

I'm trying to construct the following user experience.  There's a set of links, let's say are in the content editor web part, which control which document library is display below. How would you go about toggling the list/library source of a listview web part, based on the link that a user selected?  I was just going to try and make seperate calls to the REST API using jQuery for SharePoint, but it seems like I'd have to manually construct the presentation. It be nice if I can just programmatically set some source property with the internal name of the list, then get the nicely presented view that's OOB.

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.

George

Answer (score 1):

it sounds like you are using all oob webparts. In this situation - if I'm understanding it correctly - I would use jQuery to handle your presentation. If it's custom webparts then I would handling completely different (all in the webpart itself). So, I think your on the right track by using jQuery if I'm understanding the situation correctly.